# Specialised generic protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Created a generic protocol, and a specialized one which has all generic parameters resolved.
When trying to use the specialized protocol as a variable type, Xcode gives the following error: `Protocol 'MY_SPECIALIZED_PROTOCOL_NAME' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Tried the following code.

```swift
protocol GenericFetching {
    associatedtype FetchEntity
    associatedtype FetchOptions
    associatedtype FetchResult = Result<FetchEntity, Swift.Error>
}

protocol BananaService: class, GenericFetching where
    FetchEntity == [Banana],
    FetchOptions == Int {
}

class FruitStore {
    var bananaService: BananaService

    // ... more fruity code for our steamy company ...
}
```

Expected: Swift recognises that BananaService doesn't require any further generic parameters, and allows the developer using the type for variable definitions.

Experienced: Error at the definition of `var bananaService: BananaService`.

❌ `Protocol 'BananaService' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Comment: Where is `SpecializedProtocol`?

Comment: `SpecializedProtocol` was an abstract reference to the problem. In this example `BananaService` is the specialized protocol.

Answer (score 0):

When you use generic type in protocol(`associatedtype`) you can't use the protocol as a reference, you need to make `class` inherits from the protocol and sets `typealias` of the`associatedtype`'s.

**Example:**

```
protocol BananaServiceProtocol: class, GenericFetching {

}

class BananaService: BananaServiceProtocol {
    typealias FetchEntity = [Banana]

    typealias FetchOptions = Int

}

class FruitStore {
    var bananaService: BananaService

    // ... more fruity code for our steamy company ...
}
```